# How to pass object array in url

Tags: node.js

if I have an object like this

```
value =  [
    {
        "service_id": "5cebd21f28ea9000459a654a"
    },
    {
        "service_id": "5cebbde328ea9000459a6518"
    }
]
```

how can i pass it through  the url  http://example.com/services/value
i am using the messenger platform and i want to pass my array of objects so that i can receive it and then be able to use it after i have received a response

Comment: You can do it with `POST` request

Comment: the messenger platform just gives your the option to open a url, so one has to find a way to pass these arrays in the url

Comment: What is `the messenger platform`??. `messenger-npm`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your object to a string using `JSON.stringify()` and pass the value as a string.